# Adding data to ListBox from non-UI thread with Asynchronous method WP8.1

Tags: c#, asynchronous, listbox, dispatcher, windows-phone-8.1

I have an application that has two pages: `MainPage.xaml` and `ShowResultsPage.xaml`.

My program will start an asynchronous request call in a third separate class when a button is clicked on the `MainPage`.

From there, I receive a `JSON` response and `deserialize` it asynchronously in a non-UI based thread (in the third class).

After the call is completed, I navigate to the `ShowResultsPage.xaml` where a `ListBox` is located. What I need to do is update this `ListBox` with the response I received in the asynchronous request.

I try to do this using the `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync` method to call another method from the `ShowResultsPage.xaml.cs` that would access the response from the asynchronous call and update the `ListBox`.

When this method runs it doesn't actually populate the `ListBox` on the `ShowResultsPage`.

Here is the code inside of the third class that runs the non-UI based thread:

```
    private ShowResultsPage resultsPage = new ShowResultsPage();

    private void GetResponseCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
     // Gets Response and successfully deserializes it into a List of information called "details"
        CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate()
        { 
            this.frame.Navigate(typeof(ShowResultsPage));
            resultsPage.AddToListBox(details);               
        });
    }
```

Next, it goes to the ShowResultsPage.xaml.cs and runs this method from there:

```
    public void AddToListBox(List<Station> details)
    {
        foreach (Station s in details)
        {
            this.listBoxStations.Items.Add(s.station.ToString());
        }       
    }
```

I placed a break point at the start of the AddToListBox method to make sure that it's being called, and it is, but the ListBox still remains empty.

Thank you for your time in reading this!

Comment: Are there any items in the details List? If you put a breakpoint at the end of the AddToListBox method, is there anything in the this.listBoxStations.Items? Also, the resultsPage on which you call the AddToListBox is not the same as the one which is used in this.frame.Navigate, so you're using a different instance of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this. First, send the details List as part of the navigation:

```
this.frame.Navigate(typeof(ShowResultsPage), details);
```

Then in ShowResultsPage, in OnNavigatedTo override, you can get the navigation parameter in NavigationEventArgs parameter which contains a Parameter object which you can convert to List and call AddToListBox (or, if the ListBox is not yet created when OnNavigatedTo is called, save the List locally during OnNavigatedTo and then call AddToListBox in Page.Loaded event handler)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!! I didn't know that you could get the parameter from the OnNavigedTo override.